# passive voice: "be told"

Tags: sentence-meaning, passive-voice

According to this passage:

> "Artists tell me that for a deep and true appreciation of art one must educate the eye. One must learn from experience to weigh the merits of line, of composition, of form and color. If I had eyes, how happily would I embark upon so fascinating a study! Yet I am told that, to many of you who have eyes to see, the world of art is a dark night, unexplored and unilluminated."
>
> *Three Days to See*, by Helen Keller

1- Where and when do we use "Yet I am told that" ?

2- What is the meaning of "Yet I am told that".

3- Who said the sentence "To many of you who have eyes to see, the world of art is a dark night, unexplored and unilluminated."- the artists or Helen Keller?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We use "I am told" when we wish to say that we have been informed of something, that (unnamed) people have told us about it.  Who they are is not relevant, so rather than say

**People told me that ....**

we can say it in the passive

**I was told (by people) that ...**

or simply

**I was told that...**

We can make it a present thing rather than a past thing by using the present tense:

**I am told.**

Answer (score 0):

1) and 2) **Yet** is another way of saying **but**: we use it to join two sentences that express opposing, or strongly differening, points of view.

**I am told that** means that somebody told you something, and it is unimportant who told you. It may also suggest that you have been told this on several occasions.

3) This is a good example of the dangers of passive voice: it doesn't say **who** told her that. It can't be Helen Keller, unless she was talking to herself at the time. It could be the artists, but it could equally be other people.

Helen Keller probably used passive voice because it was not important to mention who said this.

Comment: If It could be the artists, why did they say" to many of you who have eyes to see" ? They could say "to many of you who don't have eyes to see"

Comment: @bhghbhgh I think that the implication is that, even though most people do have eyes, but they don't use them- they never learn "to weigh the merits of line, of composition, of form and color".

Comment: Hi, Why did artists tell Helen Keller who was blind that, to many of you who have eyes to see, the world of art is a dark night, unexplored and unilluminated, (instead of to many of them.)

Comment: Going from direct to reported speech, the reporter changes the pronouns when necessary. Here is an example of direct speech: He said "This is for **you**". When reported by the listener (the **you** in the  sentence) it changes to "He said that this is for **me**". Helen Keller is quoting somebody else who said "..many of **those** who have eyes to see.." . When she reports it you, she excludes herself because she is blind, so she says "..many of **you** who have eyes to see..".